# Missing characters in text Java

Tags: java

I have a small string like: `"OT-0*02"`
and I have a "database" where I have the full strings `"OT-0502"` and `"OT-0602"`.
I need to locate these based on the user input, which looks like the first string above, the star marks the unknown character, and it could be anywhere.
How do I do this? I've tried fooling around with the Pattern.matches...stuff and the regex thingy but it doesn't seem to give me any solution.
This is what I've got so far
`rsz="OT-0*02";
        int cv = 0;
        while (cv < jarmu.size()-1){
            if (Pattern.matches(jarmu.get(cv).substring(9), rsz)) {
                System.out.println("fasz");
            }
            cv++;
        }`

Comment: What did you try so far? Show your effort; show your non-working code; show something.

Comment: A question should be supported by some coding efforts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a simple wildcard search where * matches any char. To do that, change all * in the user input to ., and escape everything else. Then you can use it as a pattern.

```
String userPattern = "O*-0*02";
String[] parts = userPattern.split("\\*", -1);
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length(); i++) parts[i] = "\\Q" + parts[i] + "\\E";
userPattern = String.join(".", parts);
```

Then use `****.matches(userPattern)` to check if a string matches the pattern.
Basically, you want `*` to mean "match any single char" but in regex, `.` performs this function, so you replace `*`s with `.`s. However, you don't want anything else to be interpreted as a special character, so the string is broken up into parts at the `*`s, and each part is quoted using `\Q` and `\E` to remove any special meaning, and then put together, with `.`s where the `*`s used to be. The -1 means `*`s at the ends of the string won't be lost.

Comment: * matches 0 or more occurrences of previous character. `O*-0*02` ?

Comment: I've got it working with this, but what does this do exactly? Thanks for the solution.